# YouTube API refresh token revoked with 400 code "invalid_grant" (for seemingly no reason)

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-api

This is my first post on stackoverflow. Here it goes.

I've built a server-side PHP application that involves reading/making changes to one users's YouTube account (changes to caption files). The user is authenticated with OAuth 2. I have been storing the refresh_token and making refresh requests *successfully* when the access_token expires.

But now, I seem to be getting an error, which coincidentally correlates with two things:

- User's upload of a new video
- Sunday nights

I don't know if that means anything.

The error happens when trying to refresh the access token and I'm using the same way of refreshing the token as I have previously. Here are the details:

Error message:

```
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request
[url] https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
[request] POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
User-Agent: Guzzle/2.8.6 curl/7.24.0 PHP/5.3.10
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=442147492209.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=D7eLQ5b0Mo1Y8uZ30ReWYwls&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1%2FCLvAt8V_d9sZznpg5YZdJlOJ58ufbHKL4F5Lw8PiJOg
[response] HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2012 16:28:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

If you feel like looking at the source code, it's on github. Here's the relevant line number where refresh takes place: https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/yt-subtitle-explorer/blob/master/app/YTSE/OAuth/LoginManager.php#L330

(You'll notice that I've added a check for this error and ask the administrator to reauthorize the application... but this is far from ideal)

Other posts I've looked into were telling people to use approval_prompt=force... so I am doing that.

**Edit:**
My newest suspicion is that since I am requesting offline access (approval_prompt=force) every time the administrator logs in, I keep generating new refresh_tokens (which I don't record unless no others are available). Does google's OAuth have a maximum number of "active" refresh_tokens per application? Or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: No ideas? Is there any more information I could give to help narrow down the problem?

Comment: It's not so much a YouTube API question as a general Google OAuth 2 infrastructure question. I'll retag and maybe you'll get some more attention. Also, you can try asking at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but a member of Google Developer Relations appeared to answer your last question (re: refresh tokens) in this post, saying there was an undocumented upper limit of 25. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549088/what-causes-intermittent-invalid-grant

Comment: This is possible. I was originally doing this in a way that would not keep the newest token, and if there is an limit to tokens, could be trying to use an old enough token. I've edited my code and still see the problem... but I'll double check to make sure it's working as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

please check this from [google developers pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication):

> If you receive an invalid_grant error response when attempting to use
>   a refresh token, the cause of the error may be due to the following
>   reasons:
>
> 1. Your server's clock is not in sync with NTP.
> 2. The refresh token limit
>      has been exceeded. Applications can request multiple refresh tokens to
>      access a single Google Analytics account. For example, this is useful
>      in situations where a user wants to install an application on multiple
>      machines and access the same Google Analytics account. In this case,
>      two refresh tokens are required, one for each installation. When the
>      number of refresh tokens exceeds the limit, older tokens become
>      invalid. If the application attempts to use an invalidated refresh
>      token, an invalid_grant error response is returned. The limit for each
>      unique pair of OAuth 2.0 client and Google Analytics account is 25
>      refresh tokens (note that this limit is subject to change). If the
>      application continues to request refresh tokens for the same
>      Client/Account pair, once the 26th token is issued, the 1st refresh
>      token that was previously issued will become invalid. The 27th
>      requested refresh token would invalidate the 2nd previously issued
>      token and so on.