# Google API :OAuth 2.0 authenticate return "invalid_grand" "Bad request"

Tags: php, authentication, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using code examples of YouTube Api v3

- I turned on YouTube Data API v3.
- I create Oauth Client in the developer console
- I added my url (`$app->url('google.auth.test')`) to allowed redirect URI
- I copied the client id and secret
- Then I used [example code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#add_a_channel_section)

  ```
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
      $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
      $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');//read some topics - it could help
      $client->setAccessType('offline');//read some topics - it could help
      $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
      $redirect = filter_var($app->url('google.auth.test'),
          FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);//uri of this page
      $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

          // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
          $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

          if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
              if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
                  die('The session state did not match.');
              }

              $cred = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
              dump($_GET['code']);
              dump($cred);
              dump($client->getAccessToken());
              exit;
              $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
              header('Location: ' . $redirect);
          }

          if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
              $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
          }

          // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
          if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

                  // This code creates a new, private playlist in the authorized user's
                  //some code



              $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
          } else {
              // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
              $state = mt_rand();
              $client->setState($state);
              $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

              $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
              $htmlBody = "
              <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
              <p>You need to <a href=\"{$authUrl}\">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
              ";
              return $htmlBody;
          }
  ```
- After I go to to $app-url('google.auth.test')
- I am being redirected to

  #### Authorization Required

  You need to authorize access before proceeding.

  It is OK.
- After clicking  - redirect to google auth it is OK.
- Accept google auth and redirect back to `$app-url('google.auth.test')`
- I get code and my status in get request, but `$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);`  return me error
- Dump info:
  [image: dump info]

I think I did not find some advanced google settings.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148265/analytics-api-returns-bad-request-invalid-grant / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784816/youtube-api-refresh-token-revoked-with-400-code-invalid-grant-for-seemingly-n

Comment: @d.datul1990 Thanks for the answer . But time setting did not help . I  do not get access token  , so the answer to revresh token is not relevant for me ... 
I have spent the past few days and I can not solve the problem...

Maybe somebody knows the cause of the error???